# How to read forward 1 element in loop and store element in variable in BASH

Tags: bash, shell, loops

Howdie do,

I have a list of strings that contain one item per line. What I'm looking to do is store the second element in a variable and echo it out. I have the follow code written

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST='jeremy
test
bob
test2'

for i in $LIST
do
        TEMP=$[i+1]
        echo $TEMP
done
```

Now, my thinking is, while looping through, just move the index + 1 and store that element in variable. However, when I run the code, I get the following:

```
1
1
```

LIST is basically an array, so how do you read ahead by one element and store that item as a variable and then move the index ahead one spot?

So when the script runs, it would store 'test' as temp and echo it out. Next, the index would be moved to 'bob' and store 'test2' as temp.

I've tried i++

I've tried i=i+1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LIST=( jeremy test bob test2 )

let count=0
for i in ${LIST[@]}
do
    if [[ $count -lt $((${#LIST[@]}-1)) ]]; then
        TEMP=${LIST[$((count+1))]}
    fi
    echo "LIST [$count] = ${LIST[$count]}    TEMP = $TEMP"
    ((count+=1))
done
```

output:

```
LIST [0] = jeremy    TEMP = test
LIST [1] = test    TEMP = bob
LIST [2] = bob    TEMP = test2
LIST [3] = test2    TEMP = test2
```

Comment: When I run your code, I actually receive 0 output. I'm still back tracking to see why, but I receive 0 output

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistype. Your code constantly returns test. It's not skipping to the second element and printing out. For example, when I run your code:sh final_pw.sh
test
test
test
test

Comment: You are correct. I originally read you definition of `LIST` as an array instead of a string. Sorry. You need to make `LIST` an array if you want to get the `I+1` element. Getting out of a string is a mess.

Comment: You're a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you very much. I'm a bit confused by the code itself. More specifically, $count -lt $((${#LIST[@]}-1))

Comment: The alphabet soup is fairly easy when you break it apart. The outer `$((` is the arithmetic operator, the inner `${#LIST[@]}` says get the number of elements in the array, the   `-  1` says don't do it for the last element. reading `last+1` is a bad thing. and finally the `))` are just the closing of the arithmetic operator. See simple :)

Comment: Thank you again. Just to confirm, in BASH, you have to store the arithmetic operation as $(). For example, in your if statement, you have the count <= $(3)

Comment: No. the arithmetic operator is `((` expression `))`. But if you want the value returned at the point of operation, then `$((` expression `))`. Look at my two uses in the `TEMP=` line and in the line `((count+=1))`. In the first case I need to do the math and get the value so the `$` precedes the `((`. In the second case I just want to increment `count` but do not need the value returned, so there is no `$` before the `((`.

Comment: `for i in "${LIST[@]}"`, you mean; the quoting is still needed here, lest it behave the same as `${LIST[*]}` would. Also might consider demonstrating better practices re: variable capitalization.

Comment: Well, no, they are not quite the same thing. The quoting of `"${LIST[@]}"` would return the expanded array individually quoted "jeremy" "test"... However `"${LIST[*]}"` would not work as it would return all elements as a single quoted string "jeremy test ...". As for the best practice on caps -- Amen. All caps - yuk! (but I was working with the provided source)

Answer (score 4):

I think there's some confusion here between the elements of an array ("jeremy", "test", etc) and the *indexes* of the elements (0, 1, etc). When you use `TEMP=$[i+1]`, you're trying to add 1 to "jeremy", which doesn't make any sense. You need to add 1 to *the index of* "jeremy", and get the element at that index ("test" in this case). But in order to do that, you have to loop over the array's indexes (`"${!list[@]}"` -- note the exclamation mark) rather than its elements (`"${list[@]}"`). Here's what it looks like:

```
list=(jeremy test bob test2)
for i in "${!list[@]}"; do
    thiselement="${list[i]}"
    nextelement="${list[i+1]}"
    echo "This element=$thiselement, next element=$nextelement"
done
```

output:

```
This element=jeremy, next element=test
This element=test, next element=bob
This element=bob, next element=test2
This element=test2, next element=
```

Note that for the last element, attempting to get the next one just returns the empty string. If you want something else, use a test like

```
    if (( i+1 < ${#list[@]} )); then
        nextelement="${list[i+1]}"
    else
        nextelement="End of the list"
    fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Use right syntax of `BASH array`:

```
list=(jeremy test bob test2)

for i in "${list[@]}"
do
   echo "$i"
done
```

btw avoid using all caps variable names in BASH to avoid stepping over some predefined env variable.

Comment: I like this format, but how would I read in the second input and store it as a variable? Currently, you're script loops through, but it will read each element in at a time. I need to store every 2nd element as a variable

Comment: 2nd element is simply `"${list[1]}"`

Comment: Thank you very much. Now the only question I have, is how would I move the index or in this case i+1 so that after it read jeremy, the next element it would read would be bob

Comment: @Jimmy, the better answer is "don't do that". popping a bash array is an O(n) operation (meaning it's slower based on the number of items in the array); we could tell you how to do it, but it would have bad performance, so it's better if you write your scripts to not need or want to do it. (To be fair -- it's possible to make it O(1) if you don't reindex, but that causes other bugs, since it means that `${array[0]}` is no longer the first entry).